# Are there any alternatives to the Pi Camera?

Tags: camera, web

What sort of support is there out in the wild for non-official cameras which are supported by or compatible with the Raspberry Pi, with or without use of the special interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an [entire page on elinux.org](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams) that has a list of supported cameras, complete with hardware IDs, operating system, resolutions, whether it needs a powered hub etc. It also has a list of a few to avoid. Here is a screenshot of one small bit:

[image]

Comment: AWESOME, thanks. exactly what I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of USB cameras work fine.

Some like the [Logitech C920](http://www.logitech.com/en-au/product/hd-pro-webcam-c920) even encode to H.264 which helps to push extra pixels through the USB interface